# Trigger and form codeigniter

Tags: mysql, forms, codeigniter, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have a database and form with some trigger in phpmyadmin. When I input the value manually on phpmyadmin, the trigger is executed normally. The problem is, when I input the value by form I made with codeigniter, the trigger is not executed, and there is no error. Can anybody help me?

This is the controller

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit ('No direct script access allowed');
class Pengujian extends MY_Controller
{
    public $data = array(
                    'modul'         => 'pengujian',
                    'breadcrumb'    => 'Pengujian',
                    'pesan'         => '',
                    'pagination'    => '',
                    'tabel_data'    => '',
                    'main_view'     => 'view_pengujian/pengujian_view',
                    'form_action'   => '',
                    'form_value'    => '',
                    'option_uji'    => '',
                    );
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Pengujian_model', 'pengujian', TRUE);
        $this->load->model('Peralatan_model', 'peralatan', TRUE);
        $this->load->model('Penerangan_model', 'penerangan', TRUE);
        $this->load->model('Kemudi_model', 'kemudi', TRUE);
        $this->load->model('Suspensi_model', 'suspensi', TRUE);
        $this->load->model('Banpelek_model', 'banpelek', TRUE);
        $this->load->model('Rangka_model', 'rangka', TRUE);
        $this->load->model('Rem_model', 'rem', TRUE);
        $this->load->model('Gasbuang_model', 'gasbuang', TRUE);
        $this->load->model('Mesin_model', 'mesin', TRUE);
        $this->load->model('Lainlain_model', 'lainlain', TRUE);
        $this->load->model('Lainlain2_model', 'lainlain2', TRUE);
        $this->load->model('Akhir_model', 'akhir', TRUE);
        $this->load->helper('form');
        //$this->load->model('Penguji_model', 'penguji', TRUE);
    }
    public function index($offset = 0)
    {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('no_pengujian_sekarang', '');
        $pengujian = $this->pengujian->cari_semua($offset);
        if ($pengujian)
        {
            $tabel = $this->pengujian->buat_tabel($pengujian);
            $this->data['tabel_data'] = $tabel;
            $this->data['pagination'] = $this->pengujian->paging(site_url('pengujian/halaman'));
        }
        else
        {
            $this->data['pesan'] = 'Tidak ada data pengujian';
        }
        $this->load->view('template', $this->data);
    }
    public function tambah1()
    {
        $this->data['breadcrumb']   = 'Pengujian > Tambah > Awal';
        $this->data['main_view']    = 'view_pengujian/pengujian_form';
        $this->data['form_action']  = 'pengujian/tambah1';
        if($this->input->post('submit'))
        {
            if($this->pengujian->validasi_tambah())
            {
                if($this->pengujian->tambah1())
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan', ' Proses tambah data berhasil');
                    redirect('pengujian/tambah2');
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->data['pesan'] = 'Proses tambah data gagal';
                    $this->load->view('template', $this->data);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->view('template', $this->data);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('template', $this->data);
        }
    }
    public function tambah2()
    {
        $this->data['breadcrumb']   = 'Pengujian > Tambah > Peralatan';
        $this->data['main_view']    = 'view_pengujian/peralatan_form';
        $this->data['form_action']  = 'pengujian/tambah2';
        if($this->input->post('submit'))
        {
            if($this->peralatan->validasi_tambah())
            {
                if($this->peralatan->tambah2())
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan', ' Proses tambah data berhasil');
                    redirect('pengujian/tambah3');
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->data['pesan'] = 'Proses tambah data gagal';
                    $this->load->view('template', $this->data);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->view('template', $this->data);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('template', $this->data);
        }
    }
```

I have until tambah12 methods, for each method, it must load from 12 models too, and 12 forms.

This is model

```
private function load_form_rules_tambah()
{
    $form = array(
            array(
            'field' => 'NO_PENGUJIAN',
            'label' => 'no pengujian',
            'rules' => 'required'
            ),
            );
        return $form;
}
public function validasi_tambah()
{
    $form = $this->load_form_rules_tambah();
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($form);
    if($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
public function tambah1()
{
    $pengujian = array(
            'NO_PENGUJIAN' => $this->input->post('NO_PENGUJIAN'),
            'NO_PEMERIKSAAN' => $this->input->post('NO_PEMERIKSAAN'),
            'LOKASI_PENGUJIAN' => $this->input->post('LOKASI_PENGUJIAN'),
            'NO_KODE' => $this->input->post('NO_KODE'),
            'NO_KENDARAAN' => $this->input->post('NO_KENDARAAN'),
            'PEMILIK_KENDARAAN' => $this->input->post('PEMILIK_KENDARAAN'),
            'TYPE_MERK_PABRIK' => $this->input->post('TYPE_MERK_PABRIK'),
            'JENIS_KENDARAAN' => $this->input->post('JENIS_KENDARAAN'),
            'MULAI_DIPERGUNAKAN' => $this->input->post('MULAI_DIPERGUNAKAN'),
            'NO_LAPORAN' => $this->input->post('NO_LAPORAN'),
            'JENIS_PEMERIKSAAN' => $this->input->post('JENIS_PEMERIKSAAN'),
            'JARAK_PEMAKAIAN' => $this->input->post('JARAK_PEMAKAIAN'),
            'BERAT_KENDARAAN' => $this->input->post('BERAT_KENDARAAN'),
            'PERALATAN' => $this->input->post('PERALATAN'),
            'SISTEM_PENERANGAN' => $this->input->post('SISTEM_PENERANGAN'),
            'SISTEM_KEMUDI' => $this->input->post('SISTEM_KEMUDI'),
            'AS_DAN_SUSPENSI' => $this->input->post('AS_DAN_SUSPENSI'),
            'BAN_DAN_PELEK' => $this->input->post('BAN_DAN_PELEK'),
            'RANGKA_DAN_BODI' => $this->input->post('RANGKA_DAN_BODI'),
            'SISTEM_REM' => $this->input->post('SISTEM_REM'),
            'SISTEM_REM_GAS_BUANG' => $this->input->post('SISTEM_REM_GAS_BUANG'),
            'MESIN_TRANSMISI' => $this->input->post('MESIN_TRANSMISI'),
            'LAIN_LAIN' => $this->input->post('LAIN_LAIN'),
            'LAIN_LAIN2' => $this->input->post('LAIN_LAIN2')
            );
    //$this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->db->insert($this->db_tabel, $pengujian);
    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

and this

```
    <?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Peralatan_model extends CI_Model
{
    public $db_tabel    ='peralatan';
    //public $offset        = 0;
    //public function cari_semua($offset = 0);
    public function tambah2()
    {
        $peralatan = array(
                'NO_CHASIS' => $this->input->post('NO_CHASIS'),
                'PLAT_PABRIK_PEMBUAT' => $this->input->post('PLAT_PABRIK_PEMBUAT'),
                'PLAT_NOMOR' => $this->input->post('PLAT_NOMOR'),
                'TULISAN' => $this->input->post('TULISAN'),
                'PENGHAPUS_KACA_DEPAN' => $this->input->post('PENGHAPUS_KACA_DEPAN'),
                'KLAKSON' => $this->input->post('KLAKSON'),
                'KACA_SPION' => $this->input->post('KACA_SPION'),
                'PANDANGAN_KE_DEPAN' => $this->input->post('PANDANGAN_KE_DEPAN'),
                'KACA_PENAHAN_SINAR' => $this->input->post('KACA_PENAHAN_SINAR'),
                'ALAT_PENGENDALIAN' => $this->input->post('ALAT_PENGENDALIAN'),
                'LAMPU_INDIKASI' => $this->input->post('LAMPU_INDIKASI'),
                'SPEEDOMETER' => $this->input->post('SPEEDOMETER'),
                'PERLENGKAPAN' => $this->input->post('PERLENGKAPAN')
                );
        //$this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->db->insert($this->db_tabel, $peralatan);
        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    private function load_form_rules_tambah()
    {
        $form = array(
                array(
                'field' => 'NO_PENGUJIAN',
                'label' => 'no chasis',
                'rules' => 'required'
                ),
                );
            return $form;
    }
    public function validasi_tambah()
    {
        $form = $this->load_form_rules_tambah();
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($form);
        if($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

}
```

this is the form

```
    <?php
$form = array(
        'no pengujian' => array(
                    'name' => 'NO_PENGUJIAN',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'form_field',
                    'value' => set_value('NO_PENGUJIAN', isset($form_value['NO_PENGUJIAN']) ? $form_value['NO_PENGUJIAN'] : '')),
        'no pemeriksaan' => array(
                    'name' => 'NO_PEMERIKSAAN',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'form_field',
                    'value' => set_value('NO_PEMERIKSAAN', isset($form_value['NO_PEMERIKSAAN']) ? $form_value['NO_PEMERIKSAAN'] : '')),
        'lokasi pengujian' => array(
                    'name' => 'LOKASI_PENGUJIAN',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'form_field',
                    'value' => set_value('LOKASI_PENGUJIAN', isset($form_value['LOKASI_PENGUJIAN']) ? $form_value['LOKASI_PENGUJIAN'] : '')),
        'no kode' => array(
                    'name' => 'NO_KODE',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'form_field',
                    'value' => set_value('NO_KODE', isset($form_value['NO_KODE']) ? $form_value['NO_KODE'] : '')),
        'no kendaraan' => array(
                    'name' => 'NO_KENDARAAN',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'form_field',
                    'value' => set_value('NO_KENDARAAN', isset($form_value['NO_KENDARAAN']) ? $form_value['NO_KENDARAAN'] : '')),
        'pemilik kendaraan' => array(
                    'name' => 'PEMILIK_KENDARAAN',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'form_field',
                    'value' => set_value('PEMILIK_KENDARAAN', isset($form_value['[PEMILIK_KENDARAAN]']) ? $form_value['PEMILIK_KENDARAAN'] : '')),
        'type merk pabrik' => array(
                    'name' => 'TYPE_MERK_PABRIK',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'form_field',
                    'value' => set_value('TYPE_MERK_PABRIK', isset($form_value['TYPE_MERK_PABRIK']) ? $form_value['TYPE_MERK_PABRIK'] : '')),
        'jenis kendaraan' => array(
                    'name' => 'JENIS_KENDARAAN',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'form_field',
                    'value' => set_value('JENIS_KENDARAAN', isset($form_value['JENIS_KENDARAAN']) ? $form_value['JENIS_KENDARAAN'] : '')),
        'mulai dipergunakan' => array(
                    'name' => 'MULAI_DIPERGUNAKAN',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'form_field',
                    'value' => set_value('MULAI_DIPERGUNAKAN', isset($form_value['MULAI_DIPERGUNAKAN']) ? $form_value['MULAI_DIPERGUNAKAN'] : '')),
        'no laporan' => array(
                    'name' => 'NO_LAPORAN',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'form_field',
                    'value' => set_value('NO_LAPORAN', isset($form_value['NO_LAPORAN']) ? $form_value['NO_LAPORAN'] : '')),
        'jenis pemeriksaan' => array(
                    'name' => 'JENIS_PEMERIKSAAN',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'radio',
                    'value' => set_value('JENIS_PEMERIKSAAN', isset($_POST['JENIS_PEMERIKSAAN']))),
        'jarak pemakaian' => array(
                    'name' => 'JARAK_PEMAKAIAN',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'form_field',
                    'value' => set_value('JARAK_PEMAKAIAN', isset($form_value['JARAK_PEMAKAIAN']) ? $form_value['JARAK_PEMAKAIAN'] : '')),
        'berat kendaraan' => array(
                    'name' => 'BERAT_KENDARAAN',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'form_field',
                    'value' => set_value('BERAT_KENDARAAN', isset($form_value['BERAT_KENDARAAN']) ? $form_value['BERAT_KENDARAAN'] : '')),
        'peralatan' => array(
                    'name' => 'PERALATAN',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'value' => set_value('PERALATAN', isset($form_value['PERALATAN']) ? $form_value['PERALATAN'] : '')),
        'sistem penerangan' => array(
                    'name' => 'SISTEM_PENERANGAN',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'value' => set_value('SISTEM_PENERANGAN', isset($form_value['SISTEM_PENERANGAN']) ? $form_value['SISTEM_PENERANGAN'] : '')),
        'sistem kemudi' => array(
                    'name' => 'SISTEM_KEMUDI',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'value' => set_value('SISTEM_KEMUDI', isset($form_value['SISTEM_KEMUDI']) ? $form_value['SISTEM_KEMUDI'] : '')),
        'as dan suspensi' => array(
                    'name' => 'AS_DAN_SUSPENSI',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'value' => set_value('AS_DAN_SUSPENSI', isset($form_value['AS_DAN_SUSPENSI']) ? $form_value['AS_DAN_SUSPENSI'] : '')),
        'ban dan pelek' => array(
                    'name' => 'BAN_DAN_PELEK',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'value' => set_value('BAN_DAN_PELEK', isset($form_value['BAN_DAN_PELEK']) ? $form_value['BAN_DAN_PELEK'] : '')),
        'rangka dan bodi' => array(
                    'name' => 'RANGKA_DAN_BODI',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'value' => set_value('RANGKA_DAN_BODI', isset($form_value['RANGKA_DAN_BODI']) ? $form_value['RANGKA_DAN_BODI'] : '')),
        'sistem rem' => array(
                    'name' => 'SISTEM_REM',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'value' => set_value('SISTEM_REM', isset($form_value['SISTEM_REM']) ? $form_value['SISTEM_REM'] : '')),
        'sistem rem gas buang' => array(
                    'name' => 'SISTEM_REM_GAS_BUANG',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'value' => set_value('SISTEM_REM_GAS_BUANG', isset($form_value['SISTEM_REM_GAS_BUANG']) ? $form_value['SISTEM_REM_GAS_BUANG'] : '')),
        'mesin transmisi' => array(
                    'name' => 'MESIN_TRANSMISI',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'value' => set_value('MESIN_TRANSMISI', isset($form_value['MESIN_TRANSMISI']) ? $form_value['MESIN_TRANSMISI'] : '')),
        'lain lain' => array(
                    'name' => 'LAIN_LAIN',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'value' => set_value('LAIN_LAIN', isset($form_value['LAIN_LAIN']) ? $form_value['LAIN_LAIN'] : '')),
        'lain lain2' => array(
                    'name' => 'LAIN_LAIN2',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'value' => set_value('LAIN_LAIN2', isset($form_value['LAIN_LAIN2']) ? $form_value['LAIN_LAIN2'] : '')),
        'submit' => array(
                    'name' => 'submit',
                    'id' => 'submit',
                    'value' => 'Simpan'
                    )
                    );
?>
<h2><?php echo $breadcrumb ?></h2>
<!-- pesan start -->
<?php if (! empty($pesan)) : ?>
    <div class="pesan">
        <?php echo $pesan; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
<!-- pesan end -->

<!-- form start -->
<?php echo form_open($form_action); ?>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('No Pengujian', 'NO_PENGUJIAN'); ?>
        <?php echo form_input($form['no pengujian']); ?>
    </p>
    <?php echo form_error('NO_PENGUJIAN', '<p class = "field_error">', '</p>');?>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('No Pemeriksaan', 'NO_PEMERIKSAAN'); ?>
        <?php echo form_input($form['no pemeriksaan']); ?>
    </p>
    <?php echo form_error('NO_PEMERIKSAAN', '<p class = "field_error">', '</p>');?>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('Lokasi Pengujian', 'LOKASI_PENGUJIAN'); ?>
        <?php echo form_input($form['lokasi pengujian']); ?>
    </p>
    <?php echo form_error('LOKASI_PENGUJIAN', '<p class = "field_error">', '</p>');?>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('No Kode', 'NO_KODE'); ?>
        <?php echo form_input($form['no kode']); ?>
    </p>
    <?php echo form_error('NO_KODE', '<p class = "field_error">', '</p>');?>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('No Kendaraan', 'NO_KENDARAAN'); ?>
        <?php echo form_input($form['no kendaraan']); ?>
    </p>
    <?php echo form_error('NO_KENDARAAN', '<p class = "field_error">', '</p>');?>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('Pemilik Kendaraan', 'PEMILIK_KENDARAAN'); ?>
        <?php echo form_input($form['pemilik kendaraan']); ?>
    </p>
    <?php echo form_error('PEMILIK_KENDARAAN', '<p class = "field_error">', '</p>');?>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('Type Merk Pabrik', 'TYPE_MERK_PABRIK'); ?>
        <?php echo form_input($form['type merk pabrik']); ?>
    </p>
    <?php echo form_error('TYPE_MERK_PABRIK', '<p class = "field_error">', '</p>');?>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('Jenis Kendaraan', 'JENIS_KENDARAAN'); ?>
        <?php echo form_input($form['jenis kendaraan']); ?>
    </p>
    <?php echo form_error('JENIS_KENDARAAN', '<p class = "field_error">', '</p>');?>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('Mulai Dipergunakan', 'MULAI_DIPERGUNAKAN'); ?>
        <?php echo form_input($form['mulai dipergunakan']); ?>
    </p>
    <?php echo form_error('MULAI_DIPERGUNAKAN', '<p class = "field_error">', '</p>');?>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('No Laporan', 'NO_LAPORAN'); ?>
        <?php echo form_input($form['no laporan']); ?>
    </p>
    <?php echo form_error('NO_LAPORAN', '<p class = "field_error">', '</p>');?>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('Jenis Pemeriksaan', 'JENIS_PEMERIKSAAN'); ?>
        <?php echo form_radio('JENIS_PEMERIKSAAN', 'Utama'); ?> Utama
        <?php echo form_radio('JENIS_PEMERIKSAAN', 'Ulang'); ?> Ulang
    </p>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('Jarak Pemakaian', 'JARAK_PEMAKAIAN'); ?>
        <?php echo form_input($form['jarak pemakaian']); ?>
    </p>
    <?php echo form_error('JARAK_PEMAKAIAN', '<p class = "field_error">', '</p>');?>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('Berat Kendaraan', 'BERAT_KENDARAAN'); ?>
        <?php echo form_input($form['berat kendaraan']); ?>
    </p>
    <?php echo form_error('BERAT_KENDARAAN', '<p class = "field_error">', '</p>');?>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_submit($form['submit']); ?>
        <?php echo anchor('pengujian', 'Batal', array('class' => 'cancel')) ?>
    </p>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
<?php echo var_dump($form["no pengujian"]); ?>
```

and this

```
    <?php
$form = array(
        'no pengujian' => array(
                    'name' => 'NO_PENGUJIAN',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'form_field',
                    'value' => set_value('NO_PENGUJIAN', isset($form_value['NO_PENGUJIAN']) ? $form_value['NO_PENGUJIAN'] : '')),
        'no chasis' => array(
                    'name' => 'NO_CHASIS',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'radio',
                    'value' => set_value('NO_CHASIS', isset($_POST['NO_CHASIS']))),
        'plat pabrik pembuat' => array(
                    'name' => 'PLAT_PABRIK_PEMBUAT',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'radio',
                    'value' => set_value('PLAT_PABRIK_PEMBUAT', isset($_POST['PLAT_PABRIK_PEMBUAT']))),
        'plat nomor' => array(
                    'name' => 'PLAT_NOMOR',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'radio',
                    'value' => set_value('PLAT_NOMOR', isset($_POST['PLAT_NOMOR']))),
        'tulisan' => array(
                    'name' => 'TULISAN',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'radio',
                    'value' => set_value('TULISAN', isset($_POST['TULISAN']))),
        'penghapus kaca depan' => array(
                    'name' => 'PENGHAPUS_KACA_DEPAN',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'radio',
                    'value' => set_value('PENGHAPUS_KACA_DEPAN', isset($_POST['PENGHAPUS_KACA_DEPAN']))),
        'klakson' => array(
                    'name' => 'KLAKSON',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'radio',
                    'value' => set_value('KLAKSON', isset($_POST['KLAKSON']))),
        'kaca spion' => array(
                    'name' => 'KACA_SPION',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'radio',
                    'value' => set_value('KACA_SPION', isset($_POST['KACA_SPION']))),
        'pandangan ke depan' => array(
                    'name' => 'PANDANGAN_KE_DEPAN',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'radio',
                    'value' => set_value('PANDANGAN_KE_DEPAN', isset($_POST['PANDANGAN_KE_DEPAN']))),
        'kaca penahan sinar' => array(
                    'name' => 'KACA_PENAHAN_SINAR',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'radio',
                    'value' => set_value('KACA_PENAHAN_SINAR', isset($_POST['KACA_PENAHAN_SINAR']))),
        'alat pengendalian' => array(
                    'name' => 'ALAT_PENGENDALIAN',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'radio',
                    'value' => set_value('ALAT_PENGENDALIAN', isset($_POST['ALAT_PENGENDALIAN']))),
        'lampu indikasi' => array(
                    'name' => 'LAMPU_INDIKASI',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'radio',
                    'value' => set_value('LAMPU_INDIKASI', isset($_POST['LAMPU_INDIKASI']))),
        'speedometer' => array(
                    'name' => 'SPEEDOMETER',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'radio',
                    'value' => set_value('SPEEDOMETER', isset($_POST['SPEEDOMETER']))),
        'perlengkapan' => array(
                    'name' => 'PERLENGKAPAN',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'radio',
                    'value' => set_value('PERLENGKAPAN', isset($_POST['PERLENGKAPAN']))),
        'submit' => array(
                    'name' => 'submit',
                    'id' => 'submit',
                    'value' => 'Simpan'
                    )
                    );
?>
<h2><?php echo $breadcrumb ?></h2>
<!-- pesan start -->
<?php if (! empty($pesan)) : ?>
    <div class="pesan">
        <?php echo $pesan; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
<!-- pesan end -->

<!-- form start -->
<?php echo form_open($form_action); ?>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('No Pengujian', 'NO_PENGUJIAN'); ?>
        <?php echo form_input($form['no pengujian']); ?>
    </p>
    <?php echo form_error('NO_PENGUJIAN', '<p class = "field_error">', '</p>');?>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('No Chasis', 'NO_CHASIS'); ?>
        <?php echo form_radio('NO_CHASIS', 'Lulus'); ?> Lulus
        <?php echo form_radio('NO_CHASIS', 'Gagal'); ?> Gagal
    </p>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('Plat Pabrik Pembuat', 'PLAT_PABRIK_PEMBUAT'); ?>
        <?php echo form_radio('PLAT_PABRIK_PEMBUAT', 'Lulus'); ?> Lulus
        <?php echo form_radio('PLAT_PABRIK_PEMBUAT', 'Gagal'); ?> Gagal
    </p>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('Plat Nomor', 'PLAT_NOMOR'); ?>
        <?php echo form_radio('PLAT_NOMOR', 'Lulus'); ?> Lulus
        <?php echo form_radio('PLAT_NOMOR', 'Gagal'); ?> Gagal
    </p>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('Tulisan', 'TULISAN'); ?>
        <?php echo form_radio('TULISAN', 'Lulus'); ?> Lulus
        <?php echo form_radio('TULISAN', 'Gagal'); ?> Gagal
    </p>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('Penghapus Kaca Depan', 'PENGHAPUS_KACA_DEPAN'); ?>
        <?php echo form_radio('PENGHAPUS_KACA_DEPAN', 'Lulus'); ?> Lulus
        <?php echo form_radio('PENGHAPUS_KACA_DEPAN', 'Gagal'); ?> Gagal
    </p>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('Klakson', 'KLAKSON'); ?>
        <?php echo form_radio('KLAKSON', 'Lulus'); ?> Lulus
        <?php echo form_radio('KLAKSON', 'Gagal'); ?> Gagal
    </p>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('Kaca Spion', 'KACA_SPION'); ?>
        <?php echo form_radio('KACA_SPION', 'Lulus'); ?> Lulus
        <?php echo form_radio('KACA_SPION', 'Gagal'); ?> Gagal
    </p>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('Pandangan Ke Depan', 'PANDANGAN_KE_DEPAN'); ?>
        <?php echo form_radio('PANDANGAN_KE_DEPAN', 'Lulus'); ?> Lulus
        <?php echo form_radio('PANDANGAN_KE_DEPAN', 'Gagal'); ?> Gagal
    </p>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('Kaca Penahan Sinar', 'KACA_PENAHAN_SINAR'); ?>
        <?php echo form_radio('KACA_PENAHAN_SINAR', 'Lulus'); ?> Lulus
        <?php echo form_radio('KACA_PENAHAN_SINAR', 'Gagal'); ?> Gagal
    </p>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('Alat Pengendalian', 'ALAT_PENGENDALIAN'); ?>
        <?php echo form_radio('ALAT_PENGENDALIAN', 'Lulus'); ?> Lulus
        <?php echo form_radio('ALAT_PENGENDALIAN', 'Gagal'); ?> Gagal
    </p>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('Lampu Indikasi', 'LAMPU_INDIKASI'); ?>
        <?php echo form_radio('LAMPU_INDIKASI', 'Lulus'); ?> Lulus
        <?php echo form_radio('LAMPU_INDIKASI', 'Gagal'); ?> Gagal
    </p>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('Speedometer', 'SPEEDOMETER'); ?>
        <?php echo form_radio('SPEEDOMETER', 'Lulus'); ?> Lulus
        <?php echo form_radio('SPEEDOMETER', 'Gagal'); ?> Gagal
    </p>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('Perlengkapan', 'PERLENGKAPAN'); ?>
        <?php echo form_radio('PERLENGKAPAN', 'Lulus'); ?> Lulus
        <?php echo form_radio('PERLENGKAPAN', 'Gagal'); ?> Gagal
    </p>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_submit($form['submit']); ?>
        <?php echo anchor('pengujian', 'Batal', array('class' => 'cancel')) ?>
    </p>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

and this is the trigger form php myadmin

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_peralatan` BEFORE INSERT ON `peralatan`
 FOR EACH ROW begin 
if (new.NO_CHASIS = "Lulus" 
AND new.PLAT_PABRIK_PEMBUAT = "Lulus" 
AND new.PLAT_NOMOR = "Lulus" 
AND new.TULISAN = "Lulus" 
AND new.PENGHAPUS_KACA_DEPAN = "Lulus" 
AND new.KLAKSON = "Lulus" 
AND new.KACA_SPION = "Lulus" 
AND new.PANDANGAN_KE_DEPAN = "Lulus" 
AND new.KACA_PENAHAN_SINAR = "Lulus" 
AND new.ALAT_PENGENDALIAN = "Lulus" 
AND new.LAMPU_INDIKASI = "Lulus" 
AND new.SPEEDOMETER = "Lulus" 
AND new.PERLENGKAPAN = "Lulus") 
then 
UPDATE pengujian
SET PERALATAN = "Lulus" 
WHERE NO_PENGUJIAN = new.NO_PENGUJIAN;
else
UPDATE pengujian
SET PERALATAN = "Gagal" 
WHERE NO_PENGUJIAN = new.NO_PENGUJIAN; end if; 
end
```

and this for the last trigger

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_nilai` BEFORE INSERT ON `pengujian`
 FOR EACH ROW begin
if
(new.AS_DAN_SUSPENSI = "Lulus" AND 
new.BAN_DAN_PELEK = "Lulus" AND 
new.LAIN_LAIN = "Lulus" AND 
new.LAIN_LAIN2 = "Lulus" AND 
new.MESIN_TRANSMISI = "Lulus" AND
new.PERALATAN = "Lulus" AND
new.RANGKA_DAN_BODI = "Lulus" AND
new.SISTEM_KEMUDI = "Lulus" AND
new.SISTEM_PENERANGAN = "Lulus" AND
new.SISTEM_REM = "Lulus" AND
new.SISTEM_REM_GAS_BUANG = "Lulus") 
then 
SET new.PENILAIAN = "Lulus" ;
else
SET new.PENILAIAN = "Gagal" ; end if; 
end
```

this is the insert query

```
INSERT INTO `pengujian`(`NO_PENGUJIAN`, `NO_PEMERIKSAAN`, `LOKASI_PENGUJIAN`, `NO_KODE`, `NO_KENDARAAN`, `PEMILIK_KENDARAAN`, `TYPE_MERK_PABRIK`, `JENIS_KENDARAAN`, `MULAI_DIPERGUNAKAN`, `TANGGAL_PEMERIKSAAN`, `NO_LAPORAN`, `JENIS_PEMERIKSAAN`, `JARAK_PEMAKAIAN`, `BERAT_KENDARAAN`, `PERALATAN`, `SISTEM_PENERANGAN`, `SISTEM_KEMUDI`, `AS_DAN_SUSPENSI`, `BAN_DAN_PELEK`, `RANGKA_DAN_BODI`, `SISTEM_REM`, `SISTEM_REM_GAS_BUANG`, `MESIN_TRANSMISI`, `LAIN_LAIN`, `LAIN_LAIN2`, `PENILAIAN`, `TANGGAL_PEMERIKSAAN_BERIKUTNYA`, `CATATAN`, `PENGUJI`, `BIAYA_TOTAL`) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5],[value-6],[value-7],[value-8],[value-9],[value-10],[value-11],[value-12],[value-13],[value-14],[value-15],[value-16],[value-17],[value-18],[value-19],[value-20],[value-21],[value-22],[value-23],[value-24],[value-25],[value-26],[value-27],[value-28],[value-29],[value-30])
```

It's a little confusing...

Comment: It would be best to include some code examples and steps you've already tried so far. I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: It's generally not good application design practice to stick business logic inside something like PHPMyAdmin.  If you have things that should be happening when a form is submitted, write the SQL queries to do it.

Comment: It is hard to explain, what code should i put in here?